# This npgsqltransaction has completed it is no longer usable

Tags: npgsql

Recently we have migrated from MSSQL database to PostgreSQL database. In order to have .NET access to PostgreSQL, we are using the NpgSql ADO.NET provider for PostgreSQL. We are getting the error "This npgsqltransaction has completed it is no longer usable" from our applications sometimes. This is a rare situation due to which we are unable to find the exact cause of the issue.

Can someone let me know the cases and causes of this error?

--Kamal

Comment: You see this error when you attempt to use an NpgsqlTransaction object after it has been committed or rolled back. Without seeing some code it's impossible to know exactly what you're doing wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with Npgsql earlier versions. This was occurred because they throw when NpgsqlTransaction.Connection is accessed on a completed transaction.

It is fixed by 5.0.1 release. If you upgrade your Npgsql package to a latest this will solved.

[Issue reported in here](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/3384)

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed another case when this exception is being thrown. If you try to commit a transaction in the code for an sql command that contains an explicit transaction, it results in the exception you are asking about.

Code example:

```cs
using var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString)
await connection.OpenAsync();
var transaction = await connection.BeginTransactionAsync();
var command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = sqlScript;
var result = await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
await transaction.CommitAsync();
```

Where sqlScript contains something like this:

```
START TRANSACTION;

-- your commands here

COMMIT;
```